# Saving java object to PostgreSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, serialization, jdbc

I want to save my java object to postgresql column and i'm looking for a simple way to do so.

1. what type for columns stores objects ?
2. I heard about serialization but i'm kind of lost. How can i serialize/deserialize object ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no specific column type. DB's like PostgreSQL doesn't understand Java. Serialization is indeed one of the ways. All you need to do is to let the class in question implement `Serializable` like so:

```
public YourClass implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```

Then you'll be able to write it to an `ObjectOutputStream` and read from an `ObjectInputStream`. You can then use `PreparedStatement#setBinaryStream()` to persist it to a binary column. In PostgreSQL, that's the `bytea` type.

```
YourClass instance = getItSomehow();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(instance);
oos.close();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray());

Connection connection = null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;

try {
    connection = database.getConnection();
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(SOME_SQL);
    preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(bais);
    // ...
```

Needless to say that this is not the best practice. Rather map your object (javabean?) to a fullworthy table wherein each column represents a property of the object. E.g.

```
public class Person {
    private Long id;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Integer age;
    // ...
}
```

Which is then mapped against such a table:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(255),
    lastname VARCHAR(255),
    age NUMERIC(3)
)
```

That's much more clear and better maintainable, reuseable and automatable.

Comment: This link, http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/HowtoserializedeserializeaJavaobjecttotheMySQLdatabase.htm has put it very easily, that is without using any ByteArrayInputStream, ObjectOutputStream, etc classes. Can you please tell me if there is a problem with that ?

Comment: I've come across this answer seeking to do similar, and it seems for some reason my compiler takes issue with:

    preparedStatement.setBinaryStream(bais);

It cannot resolve the method. I've read into the docs, and it seems like the parameter agrees with the specification, so I'm not sure what the problem is.